# Autoloader checkpoint preservation

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-autoloader

Is it possible to restore the contents of the checkpoint location after table alteration of a non-empty table ?

I am using Databricks Autoloader to load a table. I need to update the data-type of one of the columns. But, I believe this won't be allowed since the table is not empty.

Hence, I was thinking of finding a way to preserve the checkpoint location contents, then creating a separate table with the required data type, and copy the data from the old table into the new table, and finally, **replace** the previous table with the new table. However, this would delete the checkpoint location contents. Can the checkpoint be preserved and restored after replacing the table ?

Is there a work-around to this problem ?

I am very new to Databricks/Autoloader/Streaming hence requesting some pointers to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks